# Insert search box in page layout that sends results to a search results webpart in the same page layout

Tags: 2013, page-layout, search-box, search-results-webpart

I have set up a page layout that lists a Group of users based on properties on the page and in their User Profiles in a Search Result Webpart.

It Works a charm.

But I would love to include a search box, so that users can further delimit the resulting users. Ie. it finds 8 users, but I only want to see those named "Allan".

I can easily insert the web parts on a page and tell the search box webpart to send its Query to the search result webpart. But when I use Design Manager and set up the Snippet for Search Box, I can't chose the option to direct the results to my Search Result Web Part (which is also set up in the page layout).

If I chose to use this site's search settings instead, I get a HTML snippet.

In that there's a "ResultsPageAddress" property that directs me to my Search Center. I've checked out the properties for the SearchBoxScriptWebPart and I can't seem to find a property that I can change to direct it to my Search Results WP.

Hope that someone knows how to set it up...